# basic question about adding data to string

Tags: php, jquery, session

The following string contains the serialize data of a form. I want to include `session_id()` in the same string, so how can I include something like `session_id=session_id();` in it? Thanks.

```
string = '&' + $('#new_form').serialize();
```

Comment: jQuery = client-side, php = server-side -> see the problem?

Comment: In page load, you can assign php session value into a hidden form or JS variable & append it using that hidden for value or JS var value while you are serializing your form data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your form tag u can add hidden input element.

```
<form> 
<input type='hidden' name='session_id' value=<?=session_id()?> > 
<!-- your other form elements --> 
</form>
```

Now your jquery will automatically add the session_id

I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '&' + $('#new_form').serialize() + "&session_id=" + encodeURIComponent(session_id());
```